# How to update a table that is built from an inner join of two other tables

Tags: postgresql

I've created a table (PostgresSQL), "rentals_detail", based on two other tables (customer & payment) as follows:

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, payment_id, payment.amount
FROM payment
INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id;
```

The rentals_detail table comes out great. But I want to subsequently UPDATE this table whenever either the customer or payment tables get updated, and this is where I'm lost in the woods. Here is what my update logic looks like right now:

```
SET
customer_id = customer.customer_id,
first_name = customer.first_name,
last_name = customer.last_name,
payment_id = payment.payment_id,
amount = payment.amount
FROM payment, customer
WHERE payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id;
```

The problem with the above logic is that it updates the rentals_detail, in its entirety, with only the very first row from the customer table. That is, the first customer is simply copied throughout all rows of the rentals_detail table.

If I just want any and all updates to either the customer or payment tables to be applied to the rentals_detail table, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: You should use two Merge statement , one for each source tables Payment & Customer.  Vide : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MergeTestExamples

Comment: @rajorshi: As [documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) there is no MERGE statement in Postgres. The Wiki page you are linking to documents some attempts from a former GSoC. It even says in **bold** at the top of the page "**This was never integrated into PostgreSQL**"

Comment: Do not create a table *rental_details* and attempt updating it whenever a `payment` or `customer` changes. Instead just create a **VIEW** with your current query. This will then automatically reflect any changes.  BTW: Why name this rental details when it concerns only customers and payment; seems `payment_details` would be more appropriate and clearer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for pointing that out. The equivalent of MERGE statement in ORACLE/MySQL is 'INSERT ON CONFLICT' in PostgreSQL. I have demonstrated the steps to merge changes from source table to the denormalized tables below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html), You can make query like below:

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column_name [, ...] ) = [ ROW ] ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
          ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )
        } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_item [, ...] ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

Sample query:

```sql
UPDATE 
  customer u_c
SET
  customer_id = c.customer_id,
  first_name = c.first_name,
  last_name = c.last_name,
  payment_id = p.payment_id,
  amount = p.amount
FROM 
  payment p
  INNER JOIN customer c ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE
  c.id = u_c.id
```

Comment: ref:  "WHERE c.id = u_c.id" ,  But there is no 'id' in RENTALS_DETAIL table (alias U_C) as well as CUSTOMER table ( alias C).

Answer (score 1):

- This final table RENTAL_DETAIL is sourced from two tables CUSTOMER and PAYMENT.
- So, the denormalized table RENTAL_DETAIL should have CUSTOMER_ID as primary key whereas PAYMENT_ID which is the primary key of PAYMENT should be an unique key in RENTAL_DETAIL.
- These are assumed based on the question which says there can be changes in both the source tables.
- The equivalent of MERGE statement in ORACLE/MySQL is 'INSERT ON CONFLICT' in PostgreSQL vide: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/
- As mentioned in the comments , two merges will get changes in each of the source tables to the target denormalized table.

Demo:
**SET UP OF THE OBJECTs**

```
create table customer
(
  customer_id serial primary key,
  first_name varchar(20),
  last_name varchar(20)
);

create table payment
(

  payment_id serial primary key,
  customer_id int,
  amount real
);

alter table payment add  constraint customer_fkey foreign key(customer_id) references customer(customer_id);

insert into customer(first_name,last_name) select substring(md5(random()::text),1,20)  , substring(md5((random()::text)),1,20) from generate_series(1,5);
insert into payment(customer_id,amount) select a,random()*100 from generate_series(1,5) as tab(a);

create table rental_detail
as
SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, payment_id, payment.amount
FROM payment INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id;

alter table rental_detail add constraint rental_detail_pk primary key(customer_id);
alter table rental_detail add constraint rental_detail_uk  unique(payment_id);
```

Change in source table **customer**

```
update customer set first_name='dominique',last_name='root' where customer_id=5;
```

Change merged into the denormalized table **rental_detail**

```
INSERT INTO rental_detail(customer_id, first_name, last_name, payment_id,amount)   SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, payment_id, payment.amount
FROM payment INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id ON CONFLICT(payment_id)
DO UPDATE  SET payment_id=excluded.payment_id,amount=excluded.amount;
```

Change in source table **payment**

```
update payment set amount=50 where payment_id=5;
```

Change merged into the denormalized table **rental_detail**

```
INSERT INTO rental_detail(customer_id, first_name, last_name, payment_id,amount)   SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, payment_id, payment.amount
FROM payment INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id ON CONFLICT(payment_id)
DO UPDATE  SET payment_id=excluded.payment_id,amount=excluded.amount;
```

Full Execution of the mentioned steps:

```
postgres=# create table customer
postgres-# (
postgres(#   customer_id serial primary key,
postgres(#   first_name varchar(20),
postgres(#   last_name varchar(20)
postgres(# );
CREATE TABLE
postgres=#
postgres=# create table payment
postgres-# (
postgres(#
postgres(#   payment_id serial primary key,
postgres(#   customer_id int,
postgres(#   amount real
postgres(# );
CREATE TABLE
postgres=#
postgres=# alter table payment add  constraint customer_fkey foreign key(customer_id) references customer(customer_id);
ALTER TABLE
postgres=#
postgres=# insert into customer(first_name,last_name) select substring(md5(random()::text),1,20)  , substring(md5((random()::text)),1,20) from generate_series(1,5);
INSERT 0 5
postgres=# insert into payment(customer_id,amount) select a,random()*100 from generate_series(1,5) as tab(a);
INSERT 0 5
postgres=#
postgres=# select * from customer;
 customer_id |      first_name      |      last_name
-------------+----------------------+----------------------
           1 | 19326d327576dd24465a | 898a5c5694a35783d3f5
           2 | ff1ad9fd2e0451d6ccb6 | ea732337e27146c9f319
           3 | 15f596ef25243302ead5 | a44c0b71b030f9ddc3bd
           4 | 02e987944f7294441ace | 2e2c7ef9a5a1350ae9e7
           5 | 467d7508a9b5f651bd7e | 7d904eacb819a9753ac5
(5 rows)

postgres=# select * from payment;
 payment_id | customer_id |  amount
------------+-------------+-----------
          1 |           1 | 59.529808
          2 |           2 |  4.576135
          3 |           3 | 26.517262
          4 |           4 | 70.525826
          5 |           5 | 13.968032
(5 rows)

postgres=#
postgres=# create table rental_detail
postgres-# as
postgres-# SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, payment_id, payment.amount
postgres-# FROM payment INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id;
SELECT 5
postgres=#
postgres=#
postgres=# alter table rental_detail add constraint retail_detail_pk primary key(customer_id);
ALTER TABLE
postgres=# alter table rental_detail add constraint retail_detail_uk  unique(payment_id);
ALTER TABLE
postgres=#
postgres=# update payment set amount=50 where payment_id=5;
UPDATE 1
postgres=#
postgres=#
postgres=#
postgres=# INSERT INTO rental_detail(customer_id, first_name, last_name, payment_id,amount)   SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, payment_id, payment.amount
postgres-# FROM payment INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id ON CONFLICT(payment_id)
postgres-# DO UPDATE  SET payment_id=excluded.payment_id,amount=excluded.amount;
INSERT 0 5
postgres=#
postgres=#
postgres=# update customer set first_name='dominique',last_name='root' where customer_id=5;
UPDATE 1
postgres=#
postgres=#
postgres=# INSERT INTO rental_detail(customer_id, first_name, last_name, payment_id,amount)   SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, payment_id, payment.amount
postgres-# FROM payment INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id ON CONFLICT(customer_id)
postgres-# DO UPDATE  SET first_name=excluded.first_name,last_name=excluded.last_name;
INSERT 0 5
postgres=#
postgres=#
postgres=# select * from rental_detail;
 customer_id |      first_name      |      last_name       | payment_id |  amount
-------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+-----------
           1 | 19326d327576dd24465a | 898a5c5694a35783d3f5 |          1 | 59.529808
           2 | ff1ad9fd2e0451d6ccb6 | ea732337e27146c9f319 |          2 |  4.576135
           3 | 15f596ef25243302ead5 | a44c0b71b030f9ddc3bd |          3 | 26.517262
           4 | 02e987944f7294441ace | 2e2c7ef9a5a1350ae9e7 |          4 | 70.525826
           5 | dominique            | root                 |          5 |        50
(5 rows)

postgres=#
```